# OpenGL: Why the alpha channel is set to 255 while copying the texture?

Tags: opengl, alpha-transparency

I want to move and rotate a transparent BGRA image (text overlay) using OpenGL. Here is the code snippet I use:

```
glViewport(0, 0, iWidth, iHeight); // Reset The Current Viewport
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glGenTextures(1, &arTex[0].iName);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, arTex[0].iName);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, imf.iWidth, imf.iHeight, 0, GL_BGRA_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ib.GetData());

glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Note: Transparent alpha value
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glOrtho(-dAspectCanvas / 2.0, dAspectCanvas / 2.0, -0.5, 0.5, -1.0, 1.0); // Note: Using (-1.0; 1.0) for Z-planes
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glScaled(Motion.Scale.GetValue(dPosition), Motion.Scale.GetValue(dPosition), 1.0);
glTranslated(Motion.OffsetX.GetValue(dPosition) * dAspectCanvas, Motion.OffsetY.GetValue(dPosition), 0.0);
glRotated(Motion.Rotation.GetValue(dPosition), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glTranslated(Motion.PositionX.GetValue(dPosition) * dAspectCanvas, Motion.PositionY.GetValue(dPosition), 1.0);

// Rotating and moving

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, arTex[iTexIndex].iName); // has to be called outside glBegin/glEnd scope

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP); // "Many OpenGL applications avoid quads altogether because of their inherent rasterization problems"

glTexCoord2d(rcTextureIntersection.left, rcTextureIntersection.top);
glVertex2d(rcVertexIntersection.left, rcVertexIntersection.top);
glTexCoord2d(rcTextureIntersection.right, rcTextureIntersection.top);
glVertex2d(rcVertexIntersection.right, rcVertexIntersection.top);
glTexCoord2d(rcTextureIntersection.left, rcTextureIntersection.bottom);
glVertex2d(rcVertexIntersection.left, rcVertexIntersection.bottom);
glTexCoord2d(rcTextureIntersection.right, rcTextureIntersection.bottom);
glVertex2d(rcVertexIntersection.right, rcVertexIntersection.bottom);
glEnd();

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glFlush();   
glReadBuffer(GL_BACK);
glReadPixels(0, 0, imf.iWidth, imf.iHeight, GL_BGRA_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ibOut.GetData());
```

But whatever I try in glTexImage2D, my transparent black image becomes a totally opaque black image. Input BGRA image contains bytes: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 .... After the rotating, the output image contains 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0....
The A is set to 255 all the time and I can't understand why.

Comment: "After the rotating, the output image contains 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0...." When you created the OpenGL context, did you ask for the framebuffer to have alpha in it?

Answer (score 1):

You're facing two problems here. The one is, that you didn't enable blending, which has the effect, that the texture's alpha value has no effect on transparency.

The other problem – and more important for you is – that your framebuffer (where you're drawing the texture to) probably has no alpha channel and thus will default to maximum value. You don't need to enable blending to have the texture affect the framebuffer alpha value (it will just replace it). But you need a framebuffer with alpha channel to make this work. Note that getting an alpha buffer on a onscreen framebuffer is possible (and I even recommend it). But for image manipulation the framebuffer is just the wrong place. You want a safe environment for this: A *Framebuffer Object*.

Answer (score 0):

Alpha doesn't mean "transparent". Alpha by itself doesn't mean *anything*. It only gains meaning when you use that value to do something.

If you want to render an object and use the alpha to control how transparent that object is, you need to activate blending and [set up a proper blend mode](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending).

Comment: Can I start blending using these lines:
      glEnable(GL_BLEND);
      glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

Comment: @user1207865: Well, I would hope that you would read that page and understand what those lines actually do.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to blend anything, but the frame buffer needs to be set using alpha bits. That was a problem, I completely forgot about wglCreateContext.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Set the glClearColor with the correct alpha color possibly.